# WiX write user input into file not working with utf-8 symbols

Tags: utf-8, wix, windows-installer, installation, msi-gui

I have the following problem: In my installer I have a dialog that asks the user to specify a directory and one more folder. The second folder is being written in a property and after that the property is being saved in a file via `IniFile` element. If the directory contains some utf-8 characters like **"標準"** they are being displayed as question marks.

The control in the dialog:

```
<Control Id="ChangeDir" Type="PushButton" X="20" Y="180" Width="56" 
         Height="17" Text="!(loc.LocationDlgChange)" >
   <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty"  Value="LOCATION"  Order="1">1</Publish>
  <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

And the place where I write it:

```
  <Component Id="CfgLocation" Win64="yes" Guid="SOME_GUID">
    <CreateFolder />
    <!-- Product download location -->
    <IniFile Id="CfgLocation"
             Action="addLine"
             Directory="product_cfg"
             Name="application.cfg"
             Key="directory"
             Value="[LOCATION]" />
  </Component>
```

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: It was quite some time ago. I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [codepage of your package](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/codepage.html), I suspect that should help you get it working.